# I can't make a query

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I'm trying to make a query, but it doesn't show me any results. My tables are:

```
TABLE teacher_student_conn:
    id, teacher_id, student_id, created_at
TABLE users:
    user_id, username, password, school_id, class, division, role_id, deactivated_at
TABLE schools:
    school_id, school_name
```

I want to show me only these students that are in the school of the teacher and he doesn't teach them - I take the teacher from `$this->uri->segment(3)` adn school - from `$this->uri->segment(4)`. It must show these students because admin could add them to the teacher.
I don'w exactly know how to make my query to show me these students that are in the school of the teacher and he does not teach them.
My attempt for the query is:

```html
 public function select_students() {
  
        $this->db->select('users.user_id, users.username, users.school_id, users.class, users.division, users.role_id, schools.school_name, schools.region,class_divisions.division');
        $this->db->from('users');       

        $this->db->join('teacher_student_conn','teacher_student_conn.student_id=users.user_id','left');
        $this->db->join('teacher_student_conn AS T','T.teacher_id=users.user_id','left');

        $this->db->join('class_divisions','class_divisions.id=users.division','left');
        $this->db->join('schools','schools.school_id=users.school_id','left');
        $this->db->where('(users.deactivated_at = "0000-00-00 00:00:00" OR users.deactivated_at IS NULL) AND users.role_id = 1 ');

        $this->db->where('users.school_id', $this->uri->segment(4) );
        $this->db->where('teacher_student_conn.teacher_id', $this->uri->segment(3) );
        $this->db->where("teacher_student_conn.student_id IS NULL");

         
        $result=$this->db->get();
            return $result->result();
 }
```

After echo $this->db->last_query(); it shows me:

```html
SELECT users.user_id, users.username, users.school_id, users.class, users.division, users.role_id, schools.school_name, schools.region,class_divisions.division FROM users LEFT JOIN teacher_student_conn ON teacher_student_conn.student_id=users.user_id LEFT JOIN teacher_student_conn as T ON T.teacher_id=users.user_id LEFT JOIN class_divisions ON class_divisions.id=users.division LEFT JOIN schools ON schools.school_id=users.school_id WHERE (users.deactivated_at = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR users.deactivated_at IS NULL) AND users.role_id = 1 AND users.school_id = 2 AND teacher_student_conn.teacher_id = 10 AND
```

Now I used this query:

```html
 public function select_students() {
   $query=("SELECT users.user_id, users.username, users.school_id, users.class, users.division, users.role_id, schools.school_name, schools.region,class_divisions.division FROM users
    LEFT JOIN teacher_student_conn ON teacher_student_conn.student_id=users.user_id
    LEFT JOIN teacher_student_conn as T ON T.teacher_id=users.user_id
    LEFT JOIN class_divisions ON class_divisions.id=users.division
    LEFT JOIN schools ON schools.school_id=users.school_id
    WHERE (users.deactivated_at = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR users.deactivated_at IS NULL) AND users.role_id = 1 AND
    users.school_id = 2 ");
   $this->db->where('teacher_student_conn.student_id', NULL);
    $result = $this->db->query($query);
    echo $this->db->last_query();
            return $result->result();   

}
```

I found the solution:

```html
$teacher=$this->uri->segment(3);
   $query=("SELECT users.user_id, users.username, users.school_id, users.class, users.division, users.role_id, schools.school_name, schools.region,class_divisions.division FROM users
    LEFT JOIN teacher_student_conn ON teacher_student_conn.student_id=users.user_id
    AND teacher_student_conn.teacher_id = $teacher
    LEFT JOIN teacher_student_conn as T ON T.teacher_id=users.user_id
    LEFT JOIN class_divisions ON class_divisions.id=users.division
    LEFT JOIN schools ON schools.school_id=users.school_id
    WHERE (users.deactivated_at = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR users.deactivated_at IS NULL) AND users.role_id = 1 AND
    users.school_id = 2 AND teacher_student_conn.student_id IS NULL");

  
    $result = $this->db->query($query);
    echo $this->db->last_query();
            return $result->result();   

}
```

Comment: Please tell us ,What is `NOT` working ? Thanks

Comment: It doesn't show me any students. It must show me that students which don't have this teacher. I'm not sure if my query is correct in the part containing "where".

Comment: First make SQL statement ,and then go for codeignitor query syntax.

Comment: Rather than dump all of your code. Provide us the error and isolate what you post to where you think the error is stemming from.

Comment: do echo  `$this->uri->segment(3);` And `$this->uri->segment(4);` are these properly coming as expected ?  
AND        ` $result=$this->db->get();` after this use `echo $this->db->last_query();` . What it prints ?

Comment: Make sure you have records on your table or even related to other table

Comment: If you want to get all data from `users` but `password`, I think you can use small hack: `SELECT(users.*, NULL as users.password)` I'm using with [Nette Framework](http://nette.org/en/) where it works flawlessly.

Comment: I edited my question and posted what is shown after echo $this->db->last_query();

Comment: It doesn't show in query:  AND teacher_student_conn.student_id IS NULL

Comment: How can I send my database? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just sql query format print your query and paste in PHPmyadmin SQL or echo $this->db->last_query();.

```
public function select_students() {

         $query = "SELECT users.user_id, users.username, users.school_id, users.class, users.division, users.role_id, schools.school_name, schools.region,class_divisions.division FROM users"
                 . "LEFT JOIN teacher_student_conn ON teacher_student_conn.student_id=users.user_id"
                 . "LEFT JOIN teacher_student_conn as T ON T.teacher_id=users.user_id"
                 . "LEFT JOIN class_divisions ON class_divisions.id=users.division"
                 . "LEFT JOIN schools ON schools.school_id=users.school_id"
                 . "WHERE (users.deactivated_at = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR users.deactivated_at IS NULL) AND users.role_id = 1 AND "
                 . "users.school_id = ".$this->uri->segment(4)." AND teacher_student_conn.teacher_id = ".$this->uri->segment(4)." AND teacher_student_conn.student_id IS NULL";
        $result = $this->db->query($query);

        return $result->result();             
}
```

Comment: Please explain what did You do !

Comment: I wrote this query in CI . It should show only one row - student_id=16 but it doesn't show anything. In my table `teacher_student_conn`student_is is for `teacher_id`=18. His teacher is not 10 in my case and should show but it doesn't.

Comment: @iveto change `return $result->result();` into `return $result->result_array();`

Comment: I use result() because I show them as objects like that: $teacher->user_id. My logic is not correct, I think. How to show these users from table `users` that are students, studies in school_id=2 for example and that are not students of teacher_id=10 for example. How to make join with table `teacher_student_conn` these students not to be in this table for that teacher.

Comment: I found the solution, I'll edit my question to show it. :) thank you all! :)